# Are bluetooth and wifi required for location based reminders?

Tags: ios, reminders, geolocation

To get location based reminders to work, are bluetooth and wifi required to be enabled or just bluetooth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For location-based reminders, you **only** need to have the GPS turned on.  Keeping wifi on helps with locations because it allows the device to pin-point where you're located.  Wifi is not required, however.

Bluetooth is not required for location reminders **unless** you're using *iBeacons*.  If you're using *iBeacons* then bluetooth is required.

Comment: If I disable Bluetooth and/or wifi, my geofence based reminder will not work // cc @sun

Comment: Geofence-based reminders don't require bluetooth, only GPS.  Allowing *Reminders* to use wifi, also, will improve accuracy.  This is just what I said in my answer.

Comment: I understand your intiial answer. It just _seems_ that location based Reminders don't work at all without Wifi enabled, meaning that it doesn't fire or is completely inaccurate

Answer (score 1):

No, just Location Services has to be turned on with Reminders having access to Location Services.

My geo-fenced Reminders work fine without WiFi nor Bluetooth (BT) turned on.

[image: Location Services, Reminders]

Comment: Something else to check if folks aren’t seeing location-based reminders: Settings > Privacy > Location Services > System Services (bottom) > Location-Based Alerts needs to be on.